# Tty drivers android access from adb?

Tags: android, adb, tty

Can we access the `dev/tty` folder from the `adb`? Could you direct to a resource for understanding the dev folder in android?

Comment: It is pretty much the same than on regular `Linux` such as `Ubuntu`. What would you like to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can acceso to */dev/tty* on Android across **ADB** command. You need that your Android has root access. Then on GNU/Linux or Windows, install adb and execute

```
adb shell
```

Now execute su, because /dev/tty on Android need superuser permisions.

```
su
cd /dev/
ls
```